# App preferences in Settings.app

Tags: iphone, application-settings, settings.bundle, root.plist

I'm trying to achieve something similar to the "Clear History" and "Clear Cookies" cells in my apps settings (see screenshot):

[image]

I already have a few settings implemented that use toggle switches and Multi Value options.

When I edit my Root.plist the only options for an item are group, multi value, slider, text field, title & toggle switch. I'm pretty much trying to replicate the "Clear History" (ie press it once and clear an array), it doesn't store any settings or preferences, it's a one off event.

I hope that makes sense. How is this achieved?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this (yet), so you'll have to find another solution.

You could simply use a switch and check it every time your app is started for this purpose and resetting the switch programmatically (since iOS4) :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't do this. Apple have not exposed (or at least documented) the functionality. You'll either have to find some other way doing it (a toggle that causes the reset the next time the program is launched?) or just have the button in the app itself.

Comment: Aah as I feared. Thanks Stephen.